# git ignore changes but do not delete files

Tags: git

Essentially I made a mistake to not include 2 directories in `.gitignore` before I had to make some analysis. The result is that these analysis have produced an overwhelming amount of files and now I have 5000 tracked changes on my git repository. I would like to ignore those changes and make git look at my updated `.gitignore` , but I don't want to remove any of the files produced by my analysis. What is the appropriate `git` command for that please.

Is it `git reset --hard [HEAD]` ? I don't want to make any silly mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove all git cache:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

When all files are removed from the index, you can add the regular files back (the one you did not want to ignore)

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am 'Removed files from the index (now ignored)'
$ git push
```

Comment: ok thanks. what's the difference between removing `git cache` and applying `git reset --hard [HEAD]` ?

Comment: git rm --cached file will remove the file from the stage. That is, when you commit the file will be removed. git reset HEAD -- file will simply reset file in the staging area to the state where it was on the HEAD commit, i.e. will undo any changes you did to it since last commiting.

Comment: ok i got an error when removing the cache, it seems like i need to remove a `.git/index.lock` file

Comment: di you run git command as root? if yes run: 

`sudo rm -f .git/index.lock` and then follow cache remove

Comment: no i did not run as root. managed to removed anyway

Comment: suggestions :  1. rather than removing everything from the cache, remove only the 2 rogue directories : `git rm -r --cached dir1 dir2` ; 2. to rewrite the active commit, use `git commit --amend`